How to get the property of an extracted union type by the value of function parameter
I am wondering if there's a way could let ts compiler determine the type of callback in useListenAPI as

(data: number[]) => void if eventType === APIType.API1
(data: {isAdmin: boolean, data: number[]}) => void if eventType === APIType.API2

const enum APIType {
    API1 = 1,
    API2 = 2
}

interface API1{
    type: APIType.API1,
    Data: number[]
}

interface API2{
    type: APIType.API2,
    Data: {
        isAdmin: boolean,
        data: number[]
    }
}

type UnionAPI = API1 | API2;

//ts error
//'eventType' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof eventType'?
const useListenAPI = (eventType: APIType, callback: (data:Extract<UnionAPI,{type: eventType}>["Data"]) => void)) => {
    // do whatever
}

//'type: typeof eventType' will make callback is (data: number[]|{isAdmin: boolean, data: number[]}) => void
const useListenAPI = (eventType: APIType, callback: (data:Extract<UnionAPI,{type: typeof eventType}>["Data"]) => void)) => {
    // do whatever
}

I know it is solvable using generic like following but I am just wondering if there's a simpler version, or it is out of reach from ts compiler since it a runtime thing
const useListenAPI = <T,>(eventType: APIType, callback: (data:Extract<UnionAPI,{type: T}>["Data"]) => void)) => {
    // do whatever
}

useListenAPI<APIType.API1>(APIType.API1, (data) => {
    // data: number[]
})


You can use the function overloads.
Here is the example

// Overloads
function useListenAPI(eventType: APIType.API1, callback: (data: API1['Data']) => void): void;
function useListenAPI(eventType: APIType.API2, callback: (data: API2['Data']) => void): void;
function useListenAPI(eventType: APIType, callback: Function) {
    // implementation details
}

// Usage
useListenAPI(APIType.API1, (data) => {
    // data is number[]
});

useListenAPI(APIType.API2, (data) => {
    // data is { isAdmin: boolean, data: number[] }
});

Here is the doc
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

damn how can i not think of function overloads, ty!
